# projecto just show desktop background

Tags: projector

I'm using a compaq computer running Ubuntu 14.04. I've plugged in a projector and it only projects the desktop background. How can i make it show what's on the laptop screen? I'm an absolute novice, i pressed fn +f8 which someone suggested to no avail. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Press Super (windows key on keyboard) + P to change projector modes.

You may have to wait for a couple of seconds before the changes reflect.

Answer (score 1):

You can just drag the window that you want to display "out" of the laptop's screen (just pull it out of the screen, to the right or left) and the window should move to the projector screen. You can confirm if this is indeed the behaviour by trying to move the mouse point out of the laptop screen and into the projector, by pushing the mouse pointer "out" of the laptop screen.

This behaviour is called "Extended" desktop, it allows you to use projector like a second, connected monitor. To have normal (duplicate of laptop screen in projector) mode, go to Settings > Display, select "Duplicate" where it says "Extend".